# prevent click on hyperlink while dragging/holding

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, draggable, preventdefault, interact.js

I have item div elements with anchor elements as children. The size of the anchor children stretches the parent item element.

I've made the item elements draggable with the library interact.js. The items get draggable when they are hold 300ms or longer. The problem is, that the anchor link of the item child get fired when the drag is released.

How can I prevent the child from firing the hyperlink when the parent element is held/dragged?

Here is a small example of the problem

```js
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

// add class .draggable to each item
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
   items[i].classList.add("draggable");
}

// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable').draggable({
 autoScroll: true,
 hold: 300,
 // call this function on every dragmove event
 onmove: dragMoveListener,
 // call this function on every dragend event
 onend: function (event) {
  var target = event.target;
  target.style.webkitTransform =
  target.style.transform =
  'translate(0px, 0px)';

  target.setAttribute('data-x', 0);
  target.setAttribute('data-y', 0);
 }
});

// this function is calles on every dragmove event
function dragMoveListener (event) {
 var target = event.target,
   // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
   x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
   y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

 // translate the element
 target.style.webkitTransform =
  target.style.transform =
  'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

 // update the posiion attributes
 target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
 target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
};



interact('.dropzone').dropzone({

 
  ondropactivate: function (event) {
    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
  },
 
  ondragenter: function (event) {
   var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
   dropzoneElement = event.target;

   // feedback the possibility of a drop
   dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
   draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
  },
 
  ondragleave: function (event) {
   // remove the drop feedback style
   event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
   event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
  },
 
  ondrop: function (event) {
   //delete Bookmark here!
   event.relatedTarget.classList.add('drop-ok');
  },
 
  ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
   // remove active dropzone feedback
   event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
   event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEFF3;
  padding: 40px 48px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.item a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 32px 0 48px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.item a .dott {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.item.can-drop a {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.item.drop-ok {
  display: none;
}

.category {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: RGBA(127, 135, 147, 0.2);
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.dropzone {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  opacity: 0;
}
.dropzone.drop-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropzone.drop-target {
  background-color: #F15B52;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs@1.3.4/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<div class="category">
 
 <div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
   <span class="dott"></span>
  bookmark</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
 </div> 
</div>

<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

Here is my current state at Codepen:
https://codepen.io/iamrbn/pen/pKGPMz

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in** the question itself_.

Comment: I fixed the broken link to the code example

Comment: Great, still, this applies [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. Now we can help you :)

Comment: @www139 There is still no verifiable sample **within** the question, and links to external resources doesn't count, as when that link die, so will the value of this question/answers

Comment: @LGSon I didn't know how to make a sample within the question with the need of the interact.js library. But I will try to add a sample!

Comment: @iamrobin. You can add external sources in the snippet editor. Generally, I agree that it is easier to use Codepen/jsfiddle than the SO snippet editor. That's especially for things involving external sources.

Comment: @www139 and iamrobin., now I added a Stack snippet to the question so you both can see how simple that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution but it works. My first attempt failed but I think I have something that works now. I created a flag system to keep track of events. Note that I added `onstart` to the draggable instance. I had to add a 300ms timeout to match the time of the hold. It seems onstart fired immediately on mousedown despite the 300ms hold. I'm not sure how that part of your library works ;)

Anyway, wait 300ms and then set a flag of drag. Note that the variable is global for reference. Check your project variable scope before implementing this. You might want to create a public object instead to keep the global from mixing things up.

I add a click event listener to each link. When the click fired, check the hold flag status. If it is a drag, prevent the event. Otherwise, proceed to register a click. Note: I tried adding this flag evaluator code to the onend method within the draggable instance but `onend` turns out to be a `mouseup` event which fires before `click`. Therefore, the evaluation needs to happen with a `click` event. The best way to do that within the scope is with adding a `click` event to each link.

Whew! Gosh, that took probably an hour. Let me know if it works :)

```js
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

// add class .draggable to each item
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].classList.add("draggable");
  items[i].children[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(drag){
    drag = false;
    e.preventDefault()
    }
  });
}

var drag = false;

// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable').draggable({
  autoScroll: true,
  hold: 300,
  // call this function on every dragmove event
  onstart: function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      drag = true;
    },300);
  },
  onmove: dragMoveListener,
  // call this function on every dragend event
  onend: function(event) {
  
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.webkitTransform =
      target.style.transform =
      'translate(0px, 0px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', 0);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', 0);
  }
});

// this function is calles on every dragmove event
function dragMoveListener(event) {
  var target = event.target,
    // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
    x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
    y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

  // translate the element
  target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
    'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

  // update the posiion attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
};



interact('.dropzone').dropzone({


  ondropactivate: function(event) {
    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
  },

  ondragenter: function(event) {
    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
      dropzoneElement = event.target;

    // feedback the possibility of a drop
    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
    draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
  },

  ondragleave: function(event) {
    // remove the drop feedback style
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
  },

  ondrop: function(event) {
    //delete Bookmark here!
    event.relatedTarget.classList.add('drop-ok');
  },

  ondropdeactivate: function(event) {
    // remove active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEFF3;
  padding: 40px 48px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.item a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 32px 0 48px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item a .dott {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.item.can-drop a {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.item.drop-ok {
  display: none;
}

.category {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: RGBA(127, 135, 147, 0.2);
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.dropzone {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  opacity: 0;
}

.dropzone.drop-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropzone.drop-target {
  background-color: #F15B52;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs@1.3.4/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<div class="category">

  <div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <span class="dott"></span> bookmark
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><span class="dott"></span>bookmark</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

Comment: I like the idea behind this solution, thanks! But the hyperlink doesn't fire on a normal click now. Do you know why?

Comment: It could be the class is left after the click? In what situation did you click the link without it working? I.e., where was the link when you attempted a click?

Comment: without dragging the item, after refreshing the page and with only the draggable and item class on the element the normal click doesn't fire the hyperlink in my browser. Do you have an other behavior in your browser?

Comment: Oh, I realize now. You're right. It's because the class `item draggable` is always there. However, I have another idea. I can look to see if the data-x and data-y are equal to 0. If not, then prevent the click.

Comment: @iamrobin. fixed it :)

Comment: oh I am so grateful for your help! This works like a charm :) Thanks for your help and the time you spent for the solution!